# Assert action redirected to correct action/route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

How do I exercise an action to ensure it redirects to the correct action or route?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
   return RedirectToAction("Products", "Index");
}

[Test]
public void foo_redirects_to_products_index()
{
   var controller = new BarController();
   var result = controller.Foo() as RedirectToRouteResult;

   if(result == null)
      Assert.Fail("should have redirected");

   Assert.That(result.RouteData.Values["Controller"], Is.EqualTo("Products"));
   Assert.That(result.RouteData.Values["Action"], Is.EqualTo("Index"));

}
```

Comment: In MVC3, use result.RouteValues["..."].